# Automatic Suspend When Idle Doesn't Work (Sleep When Inactive After ..)

Tags: release-freya, settings, suspend

I have this problem on multiple, very different systems.

Running: 
System Settings>Power>"Sleep when inactive after:" 
Changing from default of "Never" to any value, backing out, restarting logging in and letting system idle doesn't result in a sleep event.

I can manually put the system to sleep and wake it up just fine.

I see in `/etc/systemd/logind.conf`

```
#IdleAction=ignore
#IdleActionSec=30min
```

As the default, regardless of what I set in the power control panel.

Otherwise on battery the systems in question will sleep on their own with an idle time set in the system's built in power control panel.

Is this a bug, are others having this issue??

Comment: I'm experiencing the same behavior, even when my laptop is not plugged in. It sounds like this is a bug in Elementary OS. [Here's the related ticket in Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/switchboard-plug-power/+bug/1373602).

Answer (score 2):

My work around, or un-elegant fix is thus.

Uncommenting both lines in `logind.conf` and changing `IdleAction=ignore` -to- `#IdleAction=sleep`, setting `IdleActionSec=30min` to whatever time I desire, I did `=5min`, then restarting, logging in and waiting the specified time to idle results in the system going to sleep on its own.

It would appear that when the systems are plugged in, or in the case of the desktop always such, the power control panel is useless for this setting as it is simply ignored.

Answer (score 0):

this problem is still not fixed in 6.1
my system go to suspend even though I turned it to never.
but I will try "hahacompliance" solution and will see

the suspend & suspend time are working
but when you don't want the suspend from the beginning it not work
it locked the screen after moment it goes to sleep(suspend)
and after login in your opened apps all gone
what should I do?